# Python graphics with HTML

Tags: python, html

Is there a javascript library or HTML plugin that allows me to use python graphics in an HTML page?
Perhaps an object tag or 3rd party library/plugin?
**Note:** I want only client side code.
I am not using servers.

**EDIT:** The library for graphics I want is python turtle. I want to be able to draw with python turtle in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at http://www.skulpt.org/
Skulpt is JavaScript based implementation of Python. The good thing is that it is open source so you can download the source code and implement the Skulpt API in your project or HTML file.

Not only it has Turtle module but it also offers other modules like processing, math and random module.

Answer (score 1):

[MPLD3](http://mpld3.github.io/) is matplotlib with D3 backend.
From its web page,

> The mpld3 project brings together Matplotlib, the popular Python-based graphing library, and D3js, the popular Javascript library for creating interactive data visualizations for the web. The result is a simple API for exporting your matplotlib graphics to HTML code which can be used within the browser, within standard web pages, blogs, or tools such as the IPython notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure this is what you asked for, but have you heard of [ipython notebooks](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)?